# Add one char array to another using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function like this that works correctly:

```
char* add(char* origText, char* paste)
{
    char* pointerToOrigText = origText;
    while (*pointerToOrigText!='\0')
        pointerToOrigText++;
    while (*paste!='\0')
        *pointerToOrigText++=*paste++;
    *pointerToOrigText='\0';
 }
```

Example: `origText = "abc", paste = "def"`
after function: `origText = "abcdef", paste="def"`

So I merged two strings in one. But when I use this function:

```
char* add (char* origText, char *paste)
{
    int newLength = strlen(origText) + strlen(paste)+ 1; // + '\0'
    char* newText = new char[newLength]; // we want to make sure that 2 strings will fit.

    char* pointerToNewText = newText; // pointer to char array where we will merge strings
    char* helpPointer = origText; // helps us count until '\0'

    while (*helpPointer!='\0')
    {
        *pointerToNewText=*helpPointer;
        *pointerToNewText++; *helpPointer++;
    }

    while (*paste!='\0')
    {
        *pointerToNewText=*paste;
        *pointerToNewText++; *paste++;
    }

    *pointerToNewText='\0';

    origText = newText;
    
   // cout <<origText<<endl;
}
```

Output of the outside function is:

- origText = "abc", paste = "def"
- after function: origText = "abc", paste = "def"

My book explained that it is because of this line:

```
char* newText = new char[newLength];
```

But I don't get it. Why does allocating memory in function affects pointer origText?

Comment: I hope you have enough memory in origText, otherwise you'll corrupt the memory.

Comment: Please use `std::string`. Your entire function definition can be written in a single line using it. If your book recommends the way you wrote, then pick another good book.

Comment: @Mahesh +1 this book seems wrong on too many levels

Comment: @Mahesh I don't understand why C++ books (Except a few exceptions) are really C books with class instead of struct. C++ has 30 years, and nowadays people don't understand yet that C++ is not C. People think that templates are `container<T>` only, use raw-pointer and `new/delete` wherever they can, and do low-level C-style tricks thinking they are optimizing their code...

Comment: Use `std::strcat` when concatenating C-strings.

Comment: I don't think the purpose of this exercise is "how to add two strings". It's similar to the pre-school exercises like `2 + ? = 5` and everyone's saying "use a calculator because that's what they are made for".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the function, `origText` is a separate variable to the one that was passed in. So anything you do to it there (such as `origText = newText`) will *not* affect the caller's variable.

Instead, the function looks like it's supposed to return the pointer to the new string:

```
char* // That's the function's return type: it must return that
add(const char* origText, // Added const: the function doesn't change this string
    const char* paste)    // And again
{
    // Your code (with a bit more const), followed by
    return newText;
}
```

Now, when you call the function, you can use its return value:

```
const char* origText = "abc";
const char* paste = "def";

char* newText = add(origText, paste);

std::cout << origText << std::endl;    // abc - unchanged
std::cout << paste    << std::endl;    // def - unchanged
std::cout << newText  << std::endl;    // abcdef - result of concatenation

delete [] newText; // Don't forget to delete whatever you create with new.
```

Once you understand how all this nasty memory management works, you should learn to use the `std::string` class to do it all for you:

```
std::string origText = "abc";
std::string paste = "def";
std::string newText = origText + paste; // Does exactly what you think it does.
```

Answer (score 1):

*pointerToNewText++; *helpPointer++;

*pointerToNewText++; *paste++; //**wrong. Just value which pointed by pointer was increased.**

origText = newText;  //**useless.**

You should use below codes:

```
char* add (char* origText,char *paste)
{
    int newLength = strlen(origText) + strlen(paste)+ 1; // + '\0'
    char* newText = new char[newLength]; // we want to make sure that 2 strings will fit.

    char* pointerToNewText = newText; // pointer to char array where we will merge strings
    char* helpPointer = origText; // helps us count until '\0'

    while (*helpPointer!='\0')
    {
        *pointerToNewText=*helpPointer;
        pointerToNewText++; helpPointer++;
    }

    while (*paste!='\0')
    {
        *pointerToNewText=*paste;
        pointerToNewText++; paste++;
    }

    *pointerToNewText='\0';

    return newText ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the address of the string is passed by value to the function by copying to `origText` which is a local variable. The line `origText = newText;` does not change the real pointer outside. You must pass the pointer to the original pointer

```
char* add (char** origText,char *paste)
*origText = newText;
```

or use pass by reference

```
char* add (char*& origText,char *paste)
origText = newText;
```

Besides, your code does not return anything. You must return some `char*` or change the signature to return `void`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does allocating memory in function affects pointer origText.

Your version of the function just tacks extra text onto the original string, overwriting whatever was stored in memory after the original string. That may work out alright if nothing important is there, or it could cause a crash or create a security problem. The right solution is to allocate a new piece of memory that's large enough to hold the new combined string and copy both strings there.